@module-federation/typescript - Federated Types - Conflict with Jest
I'm trying to typing my modules using @module-federation/typescript
So far, is all good, follow the steps I was able to do it.
The problem right now is that when I running my tests I'm having this error:

Cannot find module './@mf-types/@testing-library/jest-dom' from
'jest.setup.js'

And is related on to have the type definitions automatically found for imports:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./@mf-types/*"]
    }
  }
}

If I remove that path, the tests works fine, but I lost the automatically type definitions.
My questions is if there is a way to fix this problem without losing the the automatically type definitions, if not how can I made by myself global definitions using the ones that the library provides me?
I have create a discussion on the repository, but no response. I want to know if someone has this problem.
Thanks!
